# Borel measure taking finitely many values

Tags: measure-theory

I was doing some problems in measure theory and came across this rather interesting problem:

> Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mu(\mathbb{R})=1$ and $\mu(A) \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ for every Borel set $A$. Show that $\mu$ only takes finitely many values.

How does one even approach this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My guess would be to try a proof by contradiction in which you show that having more than finitely many values allows you to construct a family of disjoint sets with measures such that, taking different unions of those sets, you can obtain uncountably many values. But that's just a guess.

Comment: Yea @Joe I'm pretty sure your approach works. If $ \mu $ took countably many values, we should be able to find disjoint sets of arbitrarily small measure, and then we can take unions to obtain a nested sequence of sets whose measures will approach an irrational number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Argue by contraposition: assuming $\mu$ attains infinitely many values, show that there are infinitely many disjoint sets of strictly positive measure. Then show that there is a sequence $(A_n)_n$ of disjoint sets such that $0<\mu(A_n)<\mu(A_{n-1})/4$. Given such sequence, show that the set $\{\sum_{n\in X} \mu(A_n)| X\subseteq \mathbf N \}$ is uncountable (by showing that distinct subsets of $\mathbf N$ yield distinct sums).

Answer (score 0):

From The Lebesgue  Deocompsition of a measure we have that $\mu=fdm+\nu$

where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure and $\nu$ is singular with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Also we can decompose $\nu$ to $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ where $\nu_1$ is a continuous measure and $\nu_2=\sum_{x \in A}\mu(\{x\})\delta_x$ where $A$ is a countable set and $\mu(\{x\})>0 ,\forall x \in A$

Note the the functions $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(x)dm$ and  $G(x)=\nu_1((-\infty,x])$  are continuous functions(since the measures are continuous) with values at $\Bbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ so from Intermediate Value Theorem they must be constant and so they must be zero.

So we proved that $\mu$ is a discrete measure.

If $A$ is infinite take an enumaration of $A$ to be $A=\{x_n:n\in \Bbb{N}\}$

and prove that the set $\{\sum_{n \in I}\mu(\{x_n\}):I \subseteq \Bbb{N}\}$ is uncountable.